# Why do c# objects once behave like passed by value and once as passed by reference?

Tags: c#, reference

I don't understand one thing about passing parameters to methods in c#. From what I see objects in c# sometimes behave like the have been passed by reference and once as if they were passed by value. In this code I pass to `method()` one by reference and once by value. Both of these execute as expected. But when I created `Update()` and pass an object by value I see it behaving like it is updating original object.

Why do I update original object with `Update(myString input)` but do not update it with `method(myString input)`?

This is illogical!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassPassing
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myString zmienna = new myString();

        Update(zmienna);
        Console.WriteLine(zmienna.stringValue);
        Console.WriteLine(zmienna.stringValue2);
        Console.ReadLine();

        zmienna.stringValue = "This has run in main";
        zmienna.stringValue2 = "This is a help string";

        method(zmienna);
        Console.WriteLine(zmienna.stringValue);
        Console.WriteLine(zmienna.stringValue2);
        Console.ReadLine();

        method(ref zmienna);
        Console.WriteLine(zmienna.stringValue);
        Console.WriteLine(zmienna.stringValue2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void method(myString input)
    {
        input = new myString();
    }

    static void method(ref myString input)
    {
        input = new myString();
    }

    static void Update(myString input)
    {
        input.stringValue2 = "This has run in update method";
    }
}

public class myString
{
    public string stringValue { get; set; }
    public string stringValue2 { get; set; }

    public myString() { stringValue = "This has been just constructed";   this.stringValue2 = "This has been just constructed"; }
}
```

}`

Comment: you are passing the *reference* by value, so you have two references both pointing to the same class instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand your code:

```
static void method(myString input)
{
    input = new myString();
}
```

Here you pass *reference to object by value*

```
static void method(ref myString input)
{
    input = new myString();
}
```

Here you pass *reference to object by reference*

```
static void Update(myString input)
{
    input.stringValue2 = "This has run in update method";
}
```

Here again you pass *reference to object by value*

Now:

1. When you *pass object reference by value*, you can change the contents of the object, but you cannot change the reference itself (assign it to another object).
2. When you *pass object reference by reference*, you can both change the contents of the object and you can modify the reference itself (assign it to another object).

The *real* passing by value in C# occurs only in case of simple (int, float, etc.) types and in case of `struct`s:

```
class Program 
{
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public int i;
    }

    public class MyClass 
    {
        public int i;
    }

    public static void Modify(MyStruct s) 
    {
        s.i = 99;
    }

    public static void Modify(MyClass c) 
    {
        c.i = 99;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
        myStruct.i = 20;
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.i = 20;

        Modify(myStruct);
        Modify(myClass);

        Console.WriteLine("MyStruct.i = {0}", myStruct.i);
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.i = {0}", myClass.i);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
MyStruct.i = 20
MyClass.i = 99
```

In this case, `MyStruct`'s value remained unchanged, because it was passed to a function *by value*. On the other hand, `MyClass`'s instance was passed *by reference* and that's why its value changed.

Comment: Not so much a reference to a class as a reference to an object. Again, it's important to distinguish between types and instances.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, especially that OP wants to understand how references in C# work. I've corrected the answer, now it should be OK.

Answer (score 4):

*Objects* aren't passed at all.

For expressions of a reference type (classes, interfaces etc) *references* are passed - by value by default, but the variables are passed by reference if you use `ref`.

It's important to understand that the value of `zmienna` isn't an object - it's a reference. Once you've got that sorted, the rest becomes simple. It's not just for parameter passing either - it's for *everything*. For example:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder y = x;
y.Append("Foo");
Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints Foo
```

Here the values of `x` and `y` are references to the same object - it's like having two pieces of paper, each of which has the same street address on. So if someone visits the house by reading the address written on `x` and paints the front door red, then someone else visits the same house by reading the address written on `y`, that second person will see a red front door too.

See my articles on [reference and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) and [parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple questions to answer here, but regarding your last one:

`"Why do I update original object with Update(myString input) but do not update it with method(myString input)?"`

Here, you are creating a new instance of the `myString` class and not referencing the original that was passed to the method as a parameter. So if you change the value of `input.stringValue2` inside the method, you will lose the value once you leave the method.

```
static void method(myString input)
{
    input = new myString();
}
```

But here you are referencing the original instance passed to it. When you leave this method, the original `myString` instance will retain the value of `stringValue2`.

```
static void Update(myString input)
{
    input.stringValue2 = "This has run in update method";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine computer memory as a set of boxes, and that you can give them names using labels.

```
myString zmienna = new myString();
```

Here you allocate a box with an instance of `myString` in it, and have a label `zmienna` pointing to it. Then:

```
static void method(myString input)
{
    input = new myString();
}
```

In this method, `input` is an another label. Calling the method you first make the label `input` point to the same box, with the initial instance. However in the method's body you allocate another box, and change *the label* `input` to point to that new box. Nothing is being done with the first box, and nothing is being done with `zmienna` label.

```
static void method(ref myString input)
{
    input = new myString();
}
```

Here, because of the `ref` keyword you're not only passing the whereabouts of the first "memory box", but you give the actual label. So this method's body updates your label `zmienna` to point to a newly created box, with a second instance of `myString`. The first box is being forgotten, as no labels point to it.

```
static void Update(myString input)
{
    input.stringValue2 = "This has run in update method";
}
```

In this case, you pass the address of the first box, in exactly the same manner as in the first method. So you have two labes: `zmienna` and `input` - both pointing to the same box. Therefore `input.stringValue2` accesses the field `stringValue2` in the same box that is pointed by `zmienna`.

A precise term actually used is *reference* instead of *label* term I'm using in this explanation. I somehow find that many people find it easier to comprehend this way :)